# com_error: (-2147352573, 'Memer not found.', None, None)

Tags: python, email, outlook

I'm trying to create a script that sends emails on a corporative ambient using pywin32 lib.

The user would import a .msg file and the script will read that file, copy and send the copy. But in the copy process, the attachments are lost.

I've tryied to copy the attachments using a loop cycle:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pythoncom
pythoncom CoInitialize()  
outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')  
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')  
draft_path = "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\TESTE.msg"  
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)  
for attachment in draft.Attachments:     
   try:         
      message.Attachments.Add(attachment)     
   execpt Exception as e:         
      print(f"Error adding attachment: {e}")  
message.To = exemple@mail.com 
message.HTMLbody = draft_path.HTMLbody
```

Sorry for my bad english, but I have no idea to how fix it

Edit:

When I run the script on that way it returns me a outlook message without images. When I delete the "except" it returns an empty e-mail.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also, copy error messages *exactly*. I'm certain "Memer" should be "Member". Sometimes, these details do matter.

Comment: This is not a Python issue *per se*. It's a Windows COM error (equivalent to 80020003)

Comment: Where is `draft` variable declared and initialized? `draft_path` is initialized as string, but you then access its `HTMLBody` property. Makes no sense. You set `message.To` property to something which is not a string.